# Poor performance for select2 on page with many select boxes

Tags: jquery, performance, html-select, jquery-select2

I've a page with many select boxes different by each other (about 80-100) at present, but probably slightly increasing.

I'm testing with select2 instead of standard select, but when fired at document ready the browser hangs on not so powerful computers.

What could be the solution ?

Comment: does the `select2` boxes populate values from database? Or just static values? If from database then obviously it make some time to load.

Comment: It loads from database, but I mean it is really slower then the default select tag already used in that page. It should be due to renderization time that for a few number of elements could be overlooked, but if number increases like in mine case the wait for the page ready becomes of many seconds, hanging the browser !

Comment: In a similar situation, I only put the selected option in the select box that I wanted the user to see. Then when they click on it the first time, it uses ajax to get the items for the dropdown. I use some of the select2 events to make this fetch mostly transparent to the user.

Comment: do you have some code we can look at? I have a page with 8 select2s on them and have not notices performance issues

Comment: Well, just make that page 10 times greater, my page could have 80-100 select elements